# AngularJS Directive for decimal numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want a directive in AngularJS which should allow decimal numbers between 0 and 1. In addition, it can allow "-1" as well.

For eg: 
-1 is valid
0 is valid
1 is valid
0.12 is valid
0.99 is valid
1.01 is invalid

Please let me know if you have suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "allow"? What shall the directive do exactly?

Comment: I think what @kju means is: do you want it to stop the user from typing into the input anything that doesn't meet your requirements?  or simply flag the input as invalid if it contains an invalid value? or what?

Comment: I want to stop the user from typing into the input - anything that does not meeting the requirements. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the directive should only allow decimal (-1, 0.00-1.00)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I made a directive which ignores user input if the new value will be not valid. It allows some partially written text like `0.` or `-`. Exact behaviour can be easily changed. Now it uses RegExp to find if input is a number and then tests this number for being -1 or between 0 and 1. It also allows empty string or `-`.

```
app.directive('allowZeroToOne',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
      function fromUser(text) {
        var old = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        var f = parseFloat(text);
        if(RegExp(/^(-?0*\d(\.\d*)?)$/).test(text) && (f===-1 || (f >= 0 && f <= 1)) || text==='' || text==='-') {
          return text;
        }else{
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(old);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
          return old;
        }
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  }
});
```

Oh, and now it allows any precision (so 0.111... is also valid). If you want only two digits, change `\d*` in RegExp into `\d{0,2}`. Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xjx2dzVAJ0gM6j9Jbxrq

Maybe it's kinda overkill but it was fun creating.

Comment: Done. Thanks, Lort. :)